# Project /worklight does not update after fix install using minimal-update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I installed the last fix pack available for the server side (6.3.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201504041503.zip) and run the minimal-update using the Server Configuration Tool without errors:

```
Buildfile: /root/.mobilefirst_platform_server/server-configuration-tool/Configuration_Hello MobileFirst Server/Hello MobileFirst Server.xml
minimal-admupdate:
[updateworklightadmin] Logging output of task <updateWorklightAdmin> to file /root/.mobilefirst_platform_server/configuration-logs/updateWorklightAdmin_2015_04_22_13_32_03.log
[updateworklightadmin] Copying /d01/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/worklightadmin.war to /d01/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/simpleServer/apps/worklightadmin.war
[updateworklightadmin] Copying /d01/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/worklightconsole.war to /d01/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/simpleServer/apps/worklightconsole.war
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
```

Anyway, based on this question feedback:
[Push Notification doesnt work in a liberty profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808360/push-notification-doesnt-work-in-a-liberty-profile)
we still need to update [project worklight],  because the logs are showing an older version:

> ====== Project /worklight started. The project WAR file version is 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357,running on server version 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357. [project worklight]

Is the [project worklight] not included in these war files?

Also we had and issue with the operation manager console and after the execution mentioned above, it was fixed:

> FWLSE3199I: ========= MobileFirst Administration Services version 6.3.0.00-20150404-1503 started.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project's .war is YOUR project. You need to re-deploy your .war file....
The action you've performed only upgraded the server, but the .war file is your MFP project.

Make sure your MFP Studio is updated as well, then re-build your project and redeploy the .war file (to the updated server).

Comment: Ok, I run the war update from Server Configuration Tool and now it is migrated. The problem was that we are using another war project and this project (/worklight) was installed originally by the client as part of the MobileFirst implementation.
I want be clear for our next MobileFirst fix installation, could you please confirm if the steps (and the order) below are correct: 1) Install fix at server side. 2) Install fix at development side (Studio). 3) Run minimal update to update worklightadmin.war and worklightconsole.war. 4) Update client project war file. Thanks in advance